# Hiding the DatePicker month arrows when there are no available dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, hide, future

I have a DatePicker calendar that populates with dates of given events on certain days. The problem is that I cannot figure out a way to hide the back and forward month arrows if there are no future or past available dates in the calendar. In other words, if an event only has dates in the next two months I want to disable the forward arrows when there are no future dates past those two months (so the user is not aimlessly looking through the calendar)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you set the min and max date options for the datepicker:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ 
   minDate: new Date(2012, 7, 1),
   maxDate: new Date(2012, 7, 31)
});
```

this should restrict selection to this month only. Note: javascripts month value is 0 indexed (so January is 0, December is 11 etc.)

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fjKKK/)